# Additions to org-agenda files not persisting across launches

Tags: org-mode

My init file contains the following

```
(custom-set-variables
'(org-directory "~/Dropbox/org")
'(org-agenda-files (list (concat org-directory "/mylife.org")
       (concat org-directory "/inbox.org"))))
```

which seems to work. When I add a file to org-agenda-files using `C-c [`, it works as expected for as long as Emacs is open. Once I close and relaunch Emacs, I'm back to just the original two files in org-agenda-files. Is there a way to get additions to org-agenda-files to persist?

Comment: The doc string of `org-agenda-files` suggests a different setup. Set `org-agenda-files` to a string containing the name of the file where the org agenda files are actually registered. Let us assume `(custom-set-variables  '(org-directory "~/Dropbox/org") '(org-agenda-files "~/.emacs/org-agenda-files"))`. Then store `mylife.org` as first line in `~/.emacs/org-agenda-files`. I think with you are fine to add and remove files to your org agenda files with this setup. I did not try it. Please test it and report whether it works.

Comment: The recommendation of @Tobias worked extremely well and provides the functionality I wanted.